# Amazon SES has 10 MB file limit .. Is there Any Alternate way that i can send files more than 10 MB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Amazon SES has 10 MB file limit 
 MY Question is
 Is there Any Alternate way that i can send files more than 10 MB?

Comment: Much better to not send large files through email. Consider storing them in S3 and include a public or pre-signed, time-limited URL in the email. Or use a service to share files.

Answer (score 4):

It's a hard limit.

What you'll need to do is to include URLs to the assets you're currently including in the email instead of embedding them. 10MB should be more than enough once you do that.

Update: As an added benefit, your POP clients should have better user experience, since they won't have to download all the attachments in order to, for example, view email in plain text.

Comment: Yeah I agree, but my requirement is to send the physical attachment.

Comment: Your option is to either deploy your own network of smtp servers or use a managed service by someone else. For example, sendgrid can process messages of size up to 30MB, but again, individual attachments should be less than 10MB.

Still I think the best option would be to discuss and redefine the requirements regarding the emails, since it's more likely for your emails to be classified as spam.

Comment: mewa thanks for the suggestions.we are looking to do it through ses as we have files stored in SNS.

We will pull that SNS file and attach it here.

Hope we will look forward for alternative.

Comment: Update from the current present ;-) Now you can, it doesn't appear in your account quota, you may need to do it through a support request : https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/09/amazon-ses-emails-message-40mb/

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest version upgrade (i.e. SES V2) you can [send email upto 40 MB](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/09/amazon-ses-emails-message-40mb/) in size. So you would need version upgrade as a way forward.